# Typescript response type for nextjs's fetch-api

Tags: typescript, next.js, fetch-api, next.js13, app-router

Is there a type definition for the response from the nextjs extension to the fetch-api (app router)?

I have:

```
export function getData():Promise<{any}>{
return fetch(some_url, options)
}
```

But then when I'm doing:

```
const response = await getData()
const data =await user.json()
const status= user.status
```

I'm getting a typescript error
`Property 'json' does not exist on type '{ any: any; }'.`

My trails:

1. I guess I could use [@types/node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/node-fetch) but that's a very hacky solution.
2. I went through some [the nextjs docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/fetch)